# How to access items from a debug_backtrace()?

Tags: php

In this shortened example:

`print_r($foo);`

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [function] => exception_handler
            [class] => LP
            [type] => ::
            [args] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Exception Object
                        (
                            [trace:Exception:private] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [args] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => 'hello'
                                                    [1] => 'world'
                                                )
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

How do I access the last item which is "hello".

I am lost after `$foo[0]['args'][0]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[0] => Exception Object
(
    [trace:Exception:private] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
        (
            [args] => Array
            (
                [0] => 'hello'
                [1] => 'world'
            )
        )
    )
)
```

It's an object of type [`Exception`](http://php.net/class.exception) and the values are within a (`private`) property named `trace`, thus I guess it's [`Exception::getTrace()`](http://php.net/exception.gettrace)

```
$trace = $foo[0]['args'][0]->getTrace();
echo end($trace[0]['args']);
```

... Just realize: You said "last item", but also you said "hello", so know I don't know, what you want. However, `$trace[0]['args']` is a regular array and you should be able do with it, whatever you like :) `end()` gives you the last item.

Answer (score 0):

You can access it like this **with PHP 5.4**:

```
// Only works with PHP 5.4
$foo[0]['args'][0]->getTrace()[0]['args'][0];
```